# RegEx Matching exactly; ^ and $ not completely delimiting

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to match the equivalent of EXACTLY "/mortgage/" in Google Analytics with Regex, however I'm still getting additional strings following the second "/" and other instances where the term appears as well as completely non-relevant terms.

I've tried

```
^\/mortgage\/$

^mortgage$

\bmortgage\b
```

But largely am being returned the same series of data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match exactly "/mortgage/", use:

```
^\/mortgage\/$
```

To match "/mortgage/some/other_stuff", use;

```
^\/mortgage\/.*
```

In both cases, that match is successful iff "/mortgage/" is at the start of the string.

If you are trying to see visits to /mortgage/ only, then you could do this through Custom Reports, with a filter set on the Page which matches the regex

```
^\/mortgage\/$
```

Comment: Right, so in the case of the first one, I'm still getting things like "/mortgage-foo-bar/"... How can I delimit that?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The first one matches exactly "/mortgage/". This will not match anything other than that. Are you also trying to match "/mortgage-foo-bar/"?

Comment: No. Hence my confusion, Google Analytics is still, for some reason, returning rows with line items such as, "/mortgage-foo-bar/". It's not returning the exact match.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where are using this regex, including the regex you are using?

Comment: OK, I see. The thing is that you are using an Advanced Segment with a filter that is session based. So you creating a segment where the session includes visits to "/mortgage/" only. If I go to /mortgage/ and then to /mortgage/loan-inquiry/ and then to /personal/, those would all show up still, even if I added that session filter. I've revised my answer to try to capture what I believe it is you are trying to capture.